# Prove: If $\sum a_n,\sum b_n$ are convergent series of nonnegative terms, then $\sum\sqrt{a_nb_n}$ converges.

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I am trying to use the fact that  $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}  \sqrt{s_n} =  \sqrt{s}$ where $s_n$ is the sequence of partial sums of $\sum a_n$, the same for $\sum b_n$, then I apply algebra of limits, and that is all, but I am not sure about my process.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Math.SE. Please update your question using [mathjax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). It will make it easier for people to read.

Comment: Are you assuming that $a_i, b_i$ are each nonnegative?  Otherwise $\sqrt{a_nb_n}$ is a problem.

Comment: yes, ai,bi are nonnegative.

Comment: Hint: $\sqrt{a_nb_n}\leq \max(a_n,b_n) \leq a_n+b_n$

Comment: I understand you define $s_n=\sum_{j=1}^n a_j$. Then you write "the same for $b_n$"; do you here mean that you would like to set $s_n=\sum_{j=1}^n b_j$ too? what do you have in mind exactly? :-)

Comment: No,. I mean sn=∑an and tn=∑bn, then by definition  lim sn=s and lim tn=t                   then by algebra of limits  and so ∑anbn converges,... but then I assum that if  lim sn=s and lim tn=t it is evident that lim √sn=√s and lim √tn=√t

Comment: well, using the definition of limit  I prove that lim √sn=√s and lim √tn=√t if,

Comment: then I apply algebra of limits and so, and results lim√(sn*tn)=√(s*t)  and then i guess that √(sn*tn)=∑√(an*tn) but I'm not sure of this last.

Comment: Four people have up-voted the answer, but so far I'm the only one who had up-voted the question. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** Use that $$\sqrt {a_n b_n} \leq \frac{a_n + b_n}{2}$$

if $a_n, b_n$ are non-negative. Use the Comparison Test.

Comment: Inequality of arithmetic and geometric means, well I will try.

Comment: It is useful, but I have troubles when I try to solve the case where ai, bi they are not non-negative.

Comment: When the sequences can be non negative, the result doesn't hold.

Comment: @Kolmo Something might go wrong with the square root.

Comment: @aaron Maroja: but even if it is not an issue, the theorem can fail.